# Microsoft Graph API returning no tables for shared worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-graph-api

My goal is to read and write content on an Online Excel spreadsheet that was shared with me. The operation must be performed with Microsoft Graph API in a WPF C# application. The problem is I cannot access the individual rows, only the information up to the worksheet names.

I can get the correct worksheet with the following call:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives(DRIVE_ID)/items(ITEM_ID)/workbook/worksheets(WORKSHEET_ID)/
```

for which I get the following response:

```
 {
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives(DRIVE_ID)/items(ITEM_ID)/workbook/worksheets/$entity",
"@odata.id": "/drives(DRIVE_ID)/items(ITEM_ID)/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0500-000000000000%7D%27)",
"id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0500-000000000000}",
"name": "Daniel",
"position": 5,
"visibility": "Visible"
}
```

which is correct. However, if I append a `/tables`, I get the following response

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives(DRIVE_ID)/items(ITEM_ID)/workbook/worksheets('%7B00000000-0001-0000-0500-000000000000%7D')/tables",
"value": []
}
```

which is not correct, since the worksheet has content and, without a table reference, I cannot access the tables' rows with a `/tables('0')/Rows` query.

The user I am using has read/write access to the worksheet (I can change the worksheet using the browser). On the application, I request all security scopes, even though I've read that only "files.read" and "files.readwrite" are necessary. The token is correctly granted and I can read a lot of information from the files, drives and workbooks, except the tables and therefore the rows.

The URL that I can edit using the browser is based on SharePoint. `https://COMPANY_NAME.sharepoint.com/...`

Any advice?

**Update 2017-10-08**

So you can check if the request I am doing is correct, when requesting

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/DRIVE_ID/items/ITEM_ID/workbook/worksheets
```

I get

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('b%DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets",
"value": [{
    "@odata.id": "/drives('DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000%7D%27)",
    "id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000}",
    "name": "N0",
    "position": 0,
    "visibility": "Hidden"
},
{
    "@odata.id": "/drives('b%DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0100-000000000000%7D%27)",
    "id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0100-000000000000}",
    "name": "N1",
    "position": 1,
    "visibility": "Hidden"
},
{
    "@odata.id": "/drives('b%DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0200-000000000000%7D%27)",
    "id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0200-000000000000}",
    "name": "N2",
    "position": 2,
    "visibility": "Visible"
},
{
    "@odata.id": "/drives('b%DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0300-000000000000%7D%27)",
    "id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0300-000000000000}",
    "name": "N3",
    "position": 3,
    "visibility": "Visible"
},
{
    "@odata.id": "/drives('b%DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0400-000000000000%7D%27)",
    "id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0400-000000000000}",
    "name": "N4",
    "position": 4,
    "visibility": "Visible"
},
{
    "@odata.id": "/drives('b%DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0500-000000000000%7D%27)",
    "id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0500-000000000000}",
    "name": "Daniel",
    "position": 5,
    "visibility": "Visible"
},
{
    "@odata.id": "/drives('b%DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0600-000000000000%7D%27)",
    "id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0600-000000000000}",
    "name": "N6",
    "position": 6,
    "visibility": "Visible"
},
{
    "@odata.id": "/drives('b%DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0700-000000000000%7D%27)",
    "id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0700-000000000000}",
    "name": "N7",
    "position": 7,
    "visibility": "Visible"
},
{
    "@odata.id": "/drives('b%DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0800-000000000000%7D%27)",
    "id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0800-000000000000}",
    "name": "N8",
    "position": 8,
    "visibility": "Visible"
},
{
    "@odata.id": "/drives('b%DRIVE_ID')/items('ITEM_ID')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0900-000000000000%7D%27)",
    "id": "{00000000-0001-0000-0900-000000000000}",
    "name": "N9",
    "position": 9,
    "visibility": "Visible"
}]
}
```

Also, when trying

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/DRIVE_ID/items/ITEM_ID/workbook/worksheets/00000000-0001-0000-0500-000000000000
```

then the response is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ItemNotFound",
    "message": "The requested resource doesn't exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "GUID",
      "date": "2017-10-08T07:00:0"
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, I requesting the following scope when creating the authentication token:  "user.read", "files.read.all", "files.read", "files.read.selected","files.readwrite","files.readwrite.all", "files.readwrite.selected", "sites.read.all", "sites.readwrite.all"

Comment: Just an FYI, the scope you need for this is `Files.ReadWrite.All`. This allows you to Read/Write all of the files you can access. `Files.ReadWrite` only allows you to Read/Write files you own.

Comment: Can you try `v1.0/drives/items/{item-id}/workbook/tables` as well as `v1.0/drives/items/{item-id}/workbook/worksheets/{worksheet-id|name}tables`? Note the slightly different format.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I actually have as a scope "user.read", "files.read.all", "files.read", "files.read.selected","files.readwrite","files.readwrite.all", "files.readwrite.selected", "sites.read.all", "sites.readwrite.all" and the app is authorized to access all of them and some more. I did that to make sure I was not missing anything. I will try your next suggestion now.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT by removing the DRIVE_ID parameter, the item was not found, which I think it is the expected since this is a "SharedWithMe" item. Using the format proposed, and keeping /drives/DRIVE_ID, I get the same empty tables value, except when I try the with the {worksheet-id} parameter, for which I get "resource not found". I am assuming that on the second format, I should use "/tables" instead of "tables" (slash added). I will update the question with information about the available worksheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm that the worksheet has a [table](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/table)? A table is a specific element of the worksheet and is **not** synonymous with data ranges.

To get cell values for a worksheet, you can fetch the [used range](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/worksheet_usedrange). This will give you a reference to the range containing any modified cells (cells with a format and/or value) on the sheet. You can then manipulate the range as needed.

To address your second issue, getting an ItemNotFound error when querying for a worksheet: I believe your query is not using the correct worksheet id. The ids are of the format `{<guid>}` and you are querying on `/<guid>`, not on `/{<guid>}`

Try:
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/DRIVE_ID/items/ITEM_ID/workbook/worksheets/{00000000-0001-0000-0500-000000000000}`

In place of:
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/DRIVE_ID/items/ITEM_ID/workbook/worksheets/00000000-0001-0000-0500-000000000000`

Comment: The worksheet can be accessed using /worksheets/name or /worksheets/id. The ID is enclosed in { and } characters. These characters would need URL encoding. So, it'd be something like /worksheets/%7B00000000-0001-0000-0500-000000000000%7D. If you are using worksheet name as the key note that it should be encoded as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same issue. The problem appeared to be caused by the fact that I created the tables in the desktop Excel app - not in the browser.

To fix it, I opened the desktop Excel app and removed all the tables. Then I returned to Excel online and created the tables. These are named Table1, Table2 and so on, and there is no way to rename them in Excel online - it's a known, documented, deficiency.

Graph Explorer was then able to find and list the tables.

For fun, I then reopened the worksheet in the desktop app, renamed Table1, Table2... to my liking, and Graph explorer could still find them with their new names.

Fixed.

Comment: This was also my experience. It is a big problem when loading a large number of Excel files into SharePoint Online intending to then read tables with the Graph API. I'd be interested to hear if anyone knows of a way to do that. Power Automate, maybe...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to dpim's response, I'd say first check if the file has any table at all. If there is no table involved, you can directly interact with the data using [range](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/range) object.

For range write operation, check [range update](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/range_update) API. This requires that you know the address you are working on.

For reading, you can use `GET /workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/range(address='<address>')` or if you know of name (named-item) of the range, you can use 
`GET /workbook/names/{name}/range`. If you don't know of the address or name, you can use [used range](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/worksheet_usedrange) to get all the cells that have data in it to begin.